# Python debugger not responding in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I am debugging my python code from vscode, debugger shows no response and nothing on my terminal.

I have tested it with simple hello world code with a breakpoint. No output and breakpoint is never touched.

This was working fine a day before and only change I have done is installing a PYCharm(which I have uninstalled it now).

While if I execute the program without debugger then it executes without any issue.

[image]

launch.json screennshot below:

VS already updated:

[image]

[image]

Requirements.txt screenshot:

[image]

Launch.json file code

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {"name":"Python: Current File",
            "type":"python",
            "request":"launch",
            "program":"${file}",
            "console":"integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: See this : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Already added the json config file but still no response.

Comment: what are you debugging at the moment, there is session active

Comment: Actually I am writing a bunch of code which is working but when I am trying to debug it is showing no response. So i started with basic print(Hello world) in a new python file. System is not responding, no debugging and no change in terminal window

Comment: If the debug start, the terminal should be `Python Debug Console` instead of `powershell`. Could you provide the `launch.json` file and screenshot of the `Run and Debug` Sidebar?

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: just a sanity check:
when you launch the debugger it will debug the currently selected file displayed in vscode. 
in the run and debug screenshot it looks like you are trying to debug the launch.json file.

Comment: Checked. It was in one of the screenshot but actually I am debugging the test file.

Comment: try adding "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal", "debug-test"],      to your launch.json

Comment: Added, no change in behavior.

Comment: Why didn't you uninstall and reinstall vscode ?

Comment: Done but no change in behavour

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `VScode`. One workaround you can try is to add a `requirements.txt` file like this:

```
jedi==0.15.1
parso==0.5.1
isort==4.3.21
ptvsd==5.0.0a5
pyparsing==2.4.0
six==1.12.0
packaging==19.2
```

and save it to

```
%USERPROFILE%/.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\
```

on `windows`
or

```
$HOME/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/
```

for `mac` and `linux`.

If that doesn't work, try to update the version of `VScode`. You may have an outdated version without the bug fixes. You could also try to add `stopOnEntry` and `justMyCode` to your `launch.json` file:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            // Add these lines
            "stopOnEntry": true
            "justMyCode": false

        },
}
```

You may need to add this because the default debugger will execute your file until it encounters an exception (or your program exits).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I have already tried these points and updated the requirements.txt as per your instruction but no change in behavior. VS code is already on latest version. All screenshots updated in question.

Comment: Did you also try the `"stopOnEntry": true` and  `"justMyCode": false`?

Comment: Yes. Updated the answer with launch.json code